# Silently Uninstall .Net Framework On Windows Server using any script

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012, .net-framework

I need a method which uninstalls .net framework SDK and runtime versions(preferably 4.5 or lower version) without user interaction from windows servers. msiexec /x /qr is unsuitable because it puts up a confirmation dialogue which i dont want.
Also i tried using  .NET Uninstall Tool (dotnet-core-uninstall) . i install it first on server then run    `dotnet-core-uninstall list --sdk`. But it is not giving me any sdk list while my server has sdks(screen shot attached).
**I need to uninstall it from 100+ server , so i need an automated way which i can trigger on multiple server(may be remotely).**
Thanks in advance.
[command result][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kiLia.png

Comment: .NET Framework cannot be uninstall on Windows Server 2012.  Why do you believe you need to uninstall the .NET Framework?  Newer versions of the .NET Framework are backwards compatible with itself.  ,NET Framework 4.5 is built into Windows Server 2012 and CANNOT be removed.  You can uninstall .NET Framework 3.5 using the appropriate DISM command.

Comment: I believe you are talking about the one, which comes with server itself and we can see it from registry. Yes , it is right we should not remove it from there. But i am talking about SDK version which we can see from Control Panel > Uninstall Program and which installed(or installed with some software) explicitly due to specific requirement . I need to install latest version 4.8 and then uninstall from 4.5 SDK or runtime from multiple servers.

Comment: **It is not possible to remove .NET Framework 4.5 from Windows Server 2012.**  If you install .NET Framework 4.8, which is an in-place replacement for .NET Framework 4.5, you are able to run any .NET Framework application that targets  .NET Framework 4.5+.  This isn't to be confused with .NET Core 5 (.NET 5+).  If you have already installed .NET Framework 4.8 on the system, you will have to in specific detail, explain what problem you face

Comment: @tushi0407 Perhaps you could explain why you want to do this. Because I'm sure it's not the correct solution to whatever problem you're facing.

Comment: @DanielB , we want to remove all the old frameworks whose date of end of support from microsoft already passed or it will be in near future. We just want to remove those old framework.  This may not impact anything , but we want to remove from servers

Comment: They cannot be removed. They can be updated, like Ramhound mentioned.

Comment: @tushi0407 - What you want is impossible. Even Windows 11 has a .NET Framework version built-in instead of .NET Core which is its eventual replacement.

Comment: I think , I am not able to explain it clearly. Let me give an example here : Let say i build a new server with windows 2012. This server will get .net framework 4.5 bydefault. We can see from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full . Now i installed 4.5 Software development Kit (SDK) version for my development work ,  which we can check from Control Panel. Now what i am looking is , to uninstall this SDK version using some automated way. The version which we get thru 2012 server will remain intact. I just want to uninstall this SDK version which i install .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The .NET Uninstall Tool
[dotnet-core-uninstall](https://github.com/dotnet/cli-lab)
lets you remove .NET SDKs and Runtimes from a system.
Its options can specify which versions you want to uninstall.

You may use the following parameters:

- `--sdk`
  Lists all .NET SDKs that can be uninstalled with this tool.

The tool's usage is explained in detail in the Microsoft article
[.NET Uninstall Tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool).

Comment: i tried it but it is not working. hard luck

Comment: Edit your post with how you're using the uninstall tool, commands and output both.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound for taking out time and reply on my post. I have two issues here : 1) When i try to run dotnet-core-uninstall list --sdk , it doesnt give me any list of sdk which it can uninstall while i have 4.5 and 4.6.2 sdk installed in my server. 2) Even if it able to uninstall , i can not use it. As to use this tool , i have to install it on server first. But i have more than 500 servers on which i have to perform this activity. So i dont think it is feasible to install it , on 500 servers first and then run command. I am looking some way , which i can use remotely to uninstall framework

Comment: Thanks @harrymc for taking out time and reply on my post. I have edit my post and put details there. Also i want to mention again here that Even if it is able to uninstall , i can not use it , i guess. As to use this tool , i have to install it on server first. But i have more than 500 servers on which i have to perform this activity. So i dont think it is feasible to install it , on 500 servers first and then run command. I am looking some way , which i can use remotely to uninstall framework

Comment: If the servers are identical and are in a domain, you can push whatever works on one server to all of them.

Comment: This tool applies only to .NET Core. It does not manage .NET Framework installations.

Comment: Removing .NET Framework installations is not always a good idea, so very good testing is required after removal. You'll find them listed in *Programs and Features > Installed Updates* and may uninstall using the [WUSA and DISM commands](https://www.repairwin.com/how-to-remove-windows-updates-using-wusa-and-dism-commands/). Just to remark that many people choose to keep them all, in case some program will malfunction.

Comment: @DanielB even i was suspecting so . So is there any way to uninstall framework automatically.

Comment: @harrymc  , yes we already consider risk in doing this.  Also what if , some framework SDK installed by some developers for some reason. So that will not come under updates.I already find a way like i mentioned , i used msiexec /x /qr  to uninstall but i ask for user confirmation which i want to avoid.

Comment: Try WUSA and DISM.

Comment: @Ramhound yes , but here i am talking about SDK versions (which i install on the server for my dev work).  .Net 4.5.2 which we get with server, i am not going to uninstall it..net 4.5.2 is built into that server that is true. But i install 4.5 SDK version for my dev and i want to uninstall it. Which we can do manually from Control Panel, and i did that. Now i am looking some script or automated way to uninstall this SDK version.

Comment: We can download SDK version from microsoft site and install it. Now if we want to uninstall it we can do it manually from control panel.But i have such 500+ server , so i am looking for automated way.

Comment: I'm completely lost in what you're trying to do. Between Core/Framework/SDK I have no idea what you're trying to remove. Anything you have installed you may uninstall quietly as administrator by a command such as `wusa /uninstall /kb:12345678 /quiet /norestart`.

Comment: @Ramhound [https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net452] is the link . and this is only one example . I am looking for generic way  , to uninstall any developer pack(4.5 , 4.5.1 , 4.5.2 etc) , available on any server(2012 or 2016) etc

Comment: @harrymc , i download developer pack from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework/net452 and install it on server. Now to uninstall it , i am looking for some automated way. I can try the suggested way , but from where to get these kb value ? and wusa command is used to uninstall windows update. can it be used to uninstall only framework(which i install) ?

Comment: See if it's available in *Programs and Features > Installed Updates*.

Comment: @Ramhound like i mentioned it is not about built-in framework , it is about which i install(Developer pack) due to some requirement. We want to remove older developer pack frameworks from servers. It may not be necessary but we want to do clean up on servers and want to remove any product which has end of life. So i guess it should not be any issue to remove older developer packs  and replace them with new one.

Comment: @Ramhound these are built over the span of 5-6 years by different teams. They managed their own servers and install required softwares. But for uninstalling we are planning to do it centrally and automatically and remotely.

Comment: @Ramhound: With all your comments, you have made a mess out of this answer.

Comment: to be true , i was clear since starting that i want to remove SDKs . I never talk about built-in framework. Rather to get answers , i start getting questions that why i want to do this ? it is not required etc etc. I know it may not be necessary to remove but we want to remove it(it is our requirement) as simple as that.

Comment: @tushi0407: To get back to the subject : Do you see the SDK in *Programs and Features > Installed Updates*?

Comment: No. Even i recently installed 4.7.2 manually on it and could not see under Programs and Features > Installed Updates .

Comment: You could use PowerShell to uninstall a product silently. See for example the article [How To Use PowerShell To Uninstall an Application](https://redmondmag.com/articles/2019/08/27/powershell-to-uninstall-an-application.aspx) for two methods, one of them should work for you.

Comment: I ran `Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product | Select-Object -Property Name` and getting details of frameworks but when i run `Uninstall()`, i am getting no error . But it is not uninstalling framework. **Output** i am getting is : `__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : __PARAMETERS
__SUPERCLASS     : 
__DYNASTY        : __PARAMETERS
__RELPATH        : 
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 1
__DERIVATION     : {}
__SERVER         : 
__NAMESPACE      : 
__PATH           : 
ReturnValue      : 0
PSComputerName   : `

Comment: One comment: You have mentioned trying `msiexec /x /qr`. However, according to the [documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/msiexec): "/qr : Specifies a **reduced** UI experience during the installation process". This is not the same as "/quiet : Specifies quiet mode, which means there's **no user interaction** required".

Comment: Actually i tried before with /quiet as well  but with /quiet it doesnt show any message or anything. But it didnt uninstall framework as well.

Comment: I think the conclusion is that Windows simply cannot uninstall it. The failure of the `Get-WmiObject` formulation is perhaps the best proof of that. It's perhaps too closely interwoven into the built-in Framework. My best advise is to stop trying, as forcing the issue is (1) hard to do otherwise than through Windows mechanisms, and (2) is dangerous to force manually. If `msiexec /x /qr` works, you should perhaps concentrate on falsifying the required user interaction via a program.

Comment: what i understood is , /quiet option will only work with those packages which do not asks user for confirmation to uninstall. I tried with one another package and it work for that. But for .net f/w when we trigger uninstall , it ask for user permission to uninstall . and with /quiet that popup window didnt come and it didnt uninstall as well.

Comment: if we can get way to handle those pop up windows automatically, and pass Yes to those. Then it will be automatically uninstall.

Comment: It's likely possible, but means some work. This answer was downvoted, probably by Ramhound, so I'm only keeping it because it has gathered information that might be useful for others.

Comment: is it possible that , you can help for that ?

Comment: It's most likely possible to do, but I can't guarantee my help. I suggest starting a new post, asking specifically about running `msiexec /x /qr` with automatic interaction. You may link to this post as background information.

Comment: Leave me a comment here when your new post is up and I'll try to help.

Comment: here is the new post : [https://superuser.com/questions/1686645/automate-uninstall-net-sdk-framework-using-msiexec-x]

Answer (score 0):

I just simply used the below of .net 3.5. I had to add the "" to make it work. I bet if you look up the names of the other features, dism should be the command you can use remotely.

DISM /online /disable-feature /FeatureName:"NetFx3"