# Automate Uninstall .Net SDK Framework Using msiexec /x

Tags: powershell, .net-framework, windows-server, windows-installer

I want to automate uninstalling of different .Net SDK Framework from Windows servers.

I found a way to do that using `msiexec /x`, but it asks for user confirmation to uninstall, and only when the user clicks on Yes does it proceed with the uninstall.

I want to avoid that interaction so that it will be completely automated. I tried adding `/quiet` but that doesn't help.

My question is related to this question [Silently Uninstall .Net Framework On Windows Server using any script](https://superuser.com/questions/1685132/silently-uninstall-net-framework-on-windows-server-using-any-script).

Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: I wish to add here the information that none of the methods we tried in the linked post worked without user confirmation: `dotnet-core-uninstall`, PowerShell, WUSA and DISM, they all gave the impression of success when run without confirmation, but did not do the job. Only with confirmation did it work.

Comment: Could you please [Edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1686645/edit) your post and add a screenshot of the confirmation dialog?

Comment: i added the screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to use in my answer the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following AutoHotkey script will wait for a dialog to appear with
the title of "Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7 SDK" and
will click the "Yes" button:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
WinWait, Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7 SDK
ControlGet, ControlHwnd, Hwnd,, Yes, Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7 SDK
ControlClick,, ahk_id %ControlHwnd%
ExitApp
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.

Once the script is verified as working, you can compile it by
right-click in Explorer on the `.ahk` file and selecting *Compile script*.
This will produce an `.exe` file that is stand-alone, so AutoHotkey
doesn't need to be installed on the target computer.

Note that this script will wait forever for the dialog to appear.
You may improve it by adding a
[timer](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm)
that will terminate the script (ExitApp) after a reasonable time.

If you include this script in a batch file, it needs to be called
in a non-blocking way, as by using the
[start command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start).

I have tested the script on my own test-case, which is not identical
to yours, so I blindly used values from your screenshot.
You may need to correct errors in it.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But i can not install anything on servers. I can in built tool like powershell or cmd.

Comment: It will be *much* more complicated using PowerShell.

Comment: hmm..but there are 500+ servers and we are not allowed to install anything . Also we need generic script , here it will just work for 4.7 but a server can have different f/w versions .So either i need to mention all those f/w here or i can not use it.

Comment: may be we can use some other way , ultimate goal is to uninstall framework.

Comment: The AutoHotKey script can be made more general, but no point if you can't use its compiled version.